# Iterative Combinations with Repetitons disregarding Order

Tags: combinations, genetic-algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I have the following problem. Given a set S of n elements, I need to generate all the possible combinations with repetitions disregarding order of sizes k=1,2,...,m.

Example:

```
n =3
S = {1,2,3}
```

All the possible combinations are:

```
k=1: 1,2,3

k=2: 11, 12, 13, 22, 23, 33

k=3: 111, 112, 113, 122, 123, 133, 222, 223, 233, 333.

k=4: 1111, 1112, 1113, ...

...

k=m: ...
```

Clearly, combinations at step k can be computed using the combinations obtained at k-1.
What is the best algorithm (pseudocode) and its complexity to get all combinations for all k.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most natural way to answer this question would be using recursion.

There is no real 'good' way of solving this as you will have to through each of the permutations which would give you a n^n runtime. I found this example on the net with a similar problem using java. It functions in the same way, but using a string instead of an array of ints. You should be able to make the conversion pretty easily.

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    permuteString("", "String");
  }

  public static void permuteString(String beginningString, String endingString) {
    if (endingString.length() <= 1)
      System.out.println(beginningString + endingString);
    else
      for (int i = 0; i < endingString.length(); i++) {
        try {
          String newString = endingString.substring(0, i) + endingString.substring(i + 1);

          permuteString(beginningString + endingString.charAt(i), newString);
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
          exception.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
  }
}
```

you can pretty easily add a String.Repeat(n) to recreate the varying sizes component of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 approaches, based on what you really need in your code. As the number of elements can become quite large, approach 1 might be unfeasible. Approach 2 iterates over all solutions which might be enough for you application.

**Approach 1: recursively generate all combinations**

you start with an orderded set of all your elements (in your example 1..n). This set contains all combinations of length 1.

Then create a new set to contain all combinations of length 1. You fill this by taking the elements of the previous set and appending all possible other elements that are greater then or equal to the last element.
for example: if you take the element 1 from your set, you append it with 1..n to get elements 11, 12, 13,...1n. If you take element 3, then you only append it with 3..n to get elements 33,34,...3n.
You repeat the procedure k times to get sequences of length k.

**Approach 2: iterate over the combinations**

The sets can become quite large and you could just iterate over all solutions.
Suppose you need all combinations of length k.

1. create a vector of length k and fill it with k times the first
   element (1111 for k=4)
2. replace the last element with its successor to create a new combination
   (1112). If the last element is already the biggest element in your set (n), then set it to the first and increase the second to last element. For a set of 2 elements (1 and 2), the successor of 1112 would be 1121. Do this adding recursively.

This will loop over all combinations of length k. If you also want the combination of lower length, you can find them by looking at the first part of the vector. In the example, it starts at 111 and when the last element becomes a 1 again, a new combination of length (k-1) is found (=112)